# How to study Computer Science

Tags: computer-science

I am a college student in Computer Science, I have been studying cs for a long time.
But even till today, I still feel so confused about a lot of things.
First of all, I have solid foundation in alg, data structure, and oop, but i DONT have a clear understanding of the whole system of the subject.
I studied database, alg, data structure, oop, network, software engineering, os, and a lot of courses. I know what they are, but I dont know how to connect them together. 
Is there a way to have a clear understanding of the architecture of the subject? 
And is there a way to know what technology is used to do what?

Well, I know my question maybe a little bit confusing, but what my situation is I dont even know how to ask a clear question. I dont know my question, it's totally a mess in my head. Is there a way to make it clear?

Thank you guys soooooooo much!

Comment: Try asking on http://programmers.stackexchange.com instead; this site is a bit narrow in focus, and is more about specific programming/code questions

Comment: Just use the little bits and pieces you've learned. After some practice and some "ah hah!" moments, things should start clicking together. It's the *application* of academic principles that makes software (by some miracle) work.

Comment: Thanks! I'm just kinda worry bc when people talk to each other about tech, there's a lot of terms i dont know :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to realise is you're only ever going to know the full breadth of Computer Science in generalities.

Even after a few years of experience I find myself researching topics daily to successfully complete tasks in my supposed specialty. This isn't a bad thing - the expectation for a Computer Scientist should be one of constant learning and research to find optimal solutions. The depth of information that exists in Computer Science is simply too much for one person to fully assimilate. Not only that, the constant stream of advancements will mean it's a struggle to merely keep up with the latest approaches and technologies.

As a student your expectation should be that:

- You will only ever learn the fundamental principles.
- You may begin on a path towards a specialty.
- You will acquire the capacity to apply sensible decision making to different situations.

Specifically referring to your concerns:

- Without fail the best way to learn things is to ask a lot of questions. Don't be scared to ask your friends to explain what they're talking about.
- The best technology selection is completely dependent on the specific situation. There are no black and white rules here. If there were, why would anyone ever learn different technologies that achieve largely the same thing?
- The seemingly disparate areas of knowledge you have now will increasingly become connected as you see real world examples of applying technology.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more thorough understanding of the implementation of rather abstract academic principles, you may want to study source code. Start with something open source, e.g., try to understand the implementation of threading in Linux. Pick any subject which piques your interest. Best of luck in all endeavors.